# Is there an algorithm that clips and redistributes values in an array subject to constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, greedy

I have an array `x` of real values `x_i`. Some of these values are above a threshold constant `c` and so the values above `c` need to be clipped, and the clipped amount redistributed to the other elements in the array.

The transformation of the `x_i`'s are subject to the following **constraints**:

- `x_i` < `c` for all i, where `c` is a known threshold constant
- `sum(x)` needs to be approximately zero (as close to zero as possible)
- `sum(abs(x))` needs to be less than some known constant `g`

The change in values in `x` should be minimal, so this is essentially the optimization problem.

I am not sure what type of optimization problem this is, how it can be solved (if at all) or what relevant literature to read. If anyone knows the specific type of optimization problem this is, any algorithms that can solve it, or how I can go about solving it, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a high-level model can look like:

```
min sum(|x[i]-x0[i]|)
x[i] <= c
sum(x[i]) = 0
sum(|x(i)|) <= g
```

Some code to test this out:

```
import cvxpy as cv
import numpy as np

n = 20  
c = 7 # x <= c
g = 80 # sum(abs(x)) <= g
x0 = np.random.default_rng(123).uniform(-10,+10,n)
print(f"x0:\n{x0}")

x = cv.Variable(n)

prob = cv.Problem(
    cv.Minimize(cv.sum(cv.abs(x-x0))),
    [x<=c, cv.sum(x)==0, cv.sum(cv.abs(x)) <= g]
)
prob.solve()

print(f"x:\n{x.value}")
print(f"sum(x)   :{sum(x.value)}\nsum(|x|) :{sum(np.abs(x.value))}\nmax(x)   :{max(x.value)}")
```

Output:

```
x0:
[ 3.64703726 -8.92357962 -5.59280254 -6.31256379 -6.48188198  6.24189013
  8.46689996 -4.46851204  6.39509123  7.79785386  0.2594091  -5.10070798
  6.48483192 -5.72474073  4.82934104  2.59880409  8.54814517 -5.36183623
  5.98250257  0.36330074]
x:
[ 2.42801305 -7.52326449 -4.65566667 -5.28888531 -5.43657677  4.22054525
  5.19677348 -3.65389826  4.31045304  4.97952779  0.10872304 -4.2185185
  4.3617407  -4.77234867  3.28537387  1.66750902  5.21912779 -4.45084134
  4.0620259   0.16018709]
sum(x)   :4.85722573273506e-15
sum(|x|) :79.99999999776362
max(x)   :5.219127785064835
```

Comment: Thanks for that, nice answer with a clear example. Now if only I could install cvxpy on a mac m1 chip lol... would you happen to know if this problem is solvable using [differential evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html)? Because scipy has an implementation, and scipy supports mac m1

Comment: I only use meta-heuristics when absolutely necessary. I prefer proper math programming solvers when possible (faster, more precise, and they terminate when the optimal solution is found -- heuristics just mindlessly keep on going as they don't know when they are done). Note that you can run this model on https://colab.research.google.com/.